# Results based on $sort in $lookup of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have to sort the final results based on the lookup result. Below is my aggregate query:

```
{ $match : {status:'active'},
{ $limit : 10},
{ $lookup:
  {
    from        : "metas",
    localField  : "_id",
    foreignField: "post_id",
    as          : "meta"
  }
}
```

This query produce results as:

```
  {
    "_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f294025e46e",
    "title": "Test 1",
    "created_at": "2017-06-22T06:59:40.809Z",
    "meta": [
        {
            "_id": "594b6b072a8c4f294025e46f",
            "post_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f294025e46e",
            "views": 1,
        },
        {
            "_id": "594b6b1c2a8c4f294025e471",
            "post_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f294025e46e",
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f29402f465",
    "title": "Test 2",
    "created_at": "2017-06-22T06:59:40.809Z",
    "meta": [
        {
            "_id": "594b6b072a8c4f294025e46f",
            "post_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f29402f465",
            "views": 0,
        },
        {
            "_id": "594b6b1c2a8c4f294025e471",
            "post_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f29402f465",
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f29856d442",
    "title": "Test 3",
    "created_at": "2017-06-22T06:59:40.809Z",
    "meta": [
        {
            "_id": "594b6b072a8c4f294025e46f",
            "post_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f29856d442",
            "views": 3,
        },
        {
            "_id": "594b6b1c2a8c4f294025e471",
            "post_id": "594b6adc2a8c4f29856d442",
        }
    ],
}
```

Now what I want here is to sort these results based on *'views'* under *'meta'*. Like result will be list in descending order of *'meta.views'*. First result will be meta with views=3, then views=1 and then views=0

Answer (score 3):

$unwind operator splits an array into seperate documents for each object contained in an array

For eg

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [


        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$meta"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $sort: {
              'meta.views':-1
            }
        },

    ]


);
```

Comment: Thanks @RubinPorwal . Your answer helps me 80%. Rest I also include $group.

Comment: @neeraj Could you please post your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Although *$lookup* does not support sorting, the easiest solution I think, and probably also the fastest, is to create a proper index on the related collection.

In this case, an index on the `metas` collection on the foreign field `post_id` and the field on which sorting is wanted `views`. Make sure to make the index in the correct sorting order.
Not only is the result now sorted, the query is probably also faster now it can use an index.